# How to pass context menu parameters to Java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, command, parameter-passing, contextmenu, processbuilder

I am using Java ProcessBuilder to open a file with a specific program on windows.

That itself works fine, with the following code:

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder();
p.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe", file.getAbsolutePath());
```

What I want to do is to invoke the functionality of a file context menu entry from that program which looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\program.exe" /Enqueue "%1"
```

How do I have to pass those parameters to the process builder?

I already tried the following, none of which worked:

```
p.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe","/Enqueue","%1",next.getAbsolutePath());
p.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe","Enqueue","%1",next.getAbsolutePath());
p.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe","Enqueue","\"%1\"",next.getAbsolutePath());
p.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe","/Enqueue","\"%1\"",next.getAbsolutePath());
```

"Not working" in this case meaning that the program is launched, but nothing happens (the file is not even opened).

If I switch them around in this order: (program, file, parameters) then the file is opened correctly, but the additional parameters do nothing, as if they weren't even there.

What is the correct way to translate those parameters into the ProcessBuilder command?

Comment: You need to do a `String` substitution of the value `%1` for what ever you want to pass.  You will also need to break the `String` down to an array, so that each command/parameter is a separate element

Comment: Ok, so the program is a media player with a queue, so I'm assuming the %1 is supposed to be the filename. I now tried this version: p.command("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe", "Enqueue", next.getAbsolutePath()); but it still only opens the file and nothing else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do, is make `"C:\Program Files (x86)\...\program.exe" /Enqueue "%1"` into an array of `[C:\Program Files (x86)\...\program.exe, /Enqueue, %1]` otherwise `ProcessBuilder` will try and execute the whole `String` as a single command, which really isn't what you want.

Maybe something like...

```
String cmd = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...\\program.exe\" /Enqueue \"%1\"";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(cmd);
List<String> commands = new ArrayList<>(10);
while (sb.length() > 0) {
    if (sb.charAt(0) == '"') {
        int nextIndex = sb.indexOf("\"", 1);
        if (nextIndex < 0) {
            nextIndex = sb.length();
        } else {
            nextIndex++;
        }
        commands.add(sb.substring(1, nextIndex).replace("\"", ""));
        sb.delete(0, nextIndex);
    } else if (sb.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        if (sb.length() > 1 && sb.charAt(1) != '"') {
            int nextIndex = sb.indexOf(" ", 1);
            if (nextIndex < 0) {
                nextIndex = sb.length();
            }
            commands.add(sb.substring(1, nextIndex));
            sb.delete(0, nextIndex);
        } else {
            sb.delete(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(commands);
```

Which will print...

```
[C:\Program Files (x86)\...\program.exe, /Enqueue, %1]
```

There's probably a really neat regular expression you could use to help with this, but this will get the job done, more or less.

Next, you want to replace `%1` with the file you want to open.  Now, you can do this within the previous code, which would be more efficient, but for demonstration purposes...

```
String[] parameters = {"Hello kitty"};
for (int index = 0; index < commands.size(); index++) {
    String value = commands.get(index);
    if (value.startsWith("%")) {
        int parameter = Integer.parseInt(value.substring(1)) - 1;
        if (parameter < parameters.length) {
            commands.set(index, parameters[parameter]);
        }
        // You might want to think about what you want to do if you have
        // more parameter marks then you do have actual parameter values
    }
}
System.out.println(commands);
```

Which prints out...

```
[C:\Program Files (x86)\...\program.exe, /Enqueue, Hello kitty]
```

Which you can now pass to `ProcessBuilder`, for example...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

Now, you could do the `String` substitution at many different points in the code, in many different ways, this is just an example of one

Comment: Ok, this all makes sense, unfortunately the software still doesn't behave correctly... But I'm starting to think the issue is not with the code, but with the software itself. I now noticed that calling the command from the context menu directly doesn't work properly either... so I think the java code does exactly what the actual context menu entry does (which is apperently not much...). I'm going to report this issue, otherwise thank you for your help!